# ant: condition command does not find pattern when pattern is a file path

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I am using the following code with the idea of finding a file in a directory that is also part of a list in a file:

```
    <loadfile property="ReportFileContent" srcFile="${ReportFile}"/>

<for param="file">
    <path>
        <fileset dir="${MainDir}" includes="**/**"/>
    </path>
    <sequential>
        <basename file="@{file}" property="@{file}" />

        <condition property="found-file${index2}">
            <matches pattern="@{file}" string="${ReportFileContent}"/>
        </condition>
        <if>
            <isset property="found-file${index2}"/>
            <then>
                <echo message=" Found file @{file}" level="warning" />
            </then>
            <else>
                <echo message="Not Found file @{file}" level="warning" />
            </else>
        </if>
        <math result="index2" operand1="${index2}" operation="+" operand2="1" datatype="int" />
    </sequential>
</for>
```

The  command is not working though as it is not finding the file that is available in ${ReportFileContent}.
The content of the ReportFileContent property is the following:

```
c:\___tools\test\file1.txt;2
c:\___tools\test\file2.txt;2
c:\___tools\test\file3.txt;2
```

Any idea why the condition is not working correctly?
Thanks
Tony

Comment: for task is not standard ant, part of the 3rd party ant-contrib library

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014027/map-a-list-of-strings-to-a-collection-of-file-resources-for-a-dependset/25023175#25023175

Comment: @tony: For the `<echo>` tasks, does your output have `Found file` messages, `Not Found file` messages, or neither?

Comment: It only returns 'Not Found file ..'