# How to change value of outputproperty in a for loop in ant script for an exec tast

Tags: ant, properties, exec, ant-contrib

I am trying to update ant script where I want to get new output in **outputproperty** of and **exec** task. below is my ant script.

```
<target name="print_process_list">
    <echo message="print_process_list start"/>
    <echo message="${compile_project_lists} "/>
    <echo message="print_process_list end"/>
</target>
<target name="buildall" depends="print_process_list">
    <ac:for list="${compile_project_lists}" param="iprocess">
            <sequential>
            <exec executable="./ant_xml_pars.sh" outputproperty="ant_parstout" failonerror="false" >
                                    <arg value="@{iprocess}"/>
                            </exec>
                            <echo message="${ant_parstout} " />
        </sequential>
    </ac:for>
```

**ant_xml_pars.sh** gives output based on **iprocess** passed from the list.
**ant_parstout** takes the first iteration output. but its value does not change for later iterations in the loop.
My requirement is to get the output in **ant_parstout** based on the process passed as argument.
I tried **macrodef** but not success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading the [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) documentation and use the [variable](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) task instead of an ANT property.

ANT is not a programming language as evidenced by the fact that properties in ANT are [immutable](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html). To work around these limitations some people use the [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) extension to ANT, adding tasks like "for". Personally I favour embedding scripts within ANT rather that trying to program a loop in XML...

Example embedded groovy script:

- [Map a list of strings to a collection of file resources for a dependset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014027/map-a-list-of-strings-to-a-collection-of-file-resources-for-a-dependset/25023175#25023175)

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old, but I just had the same problem, so here is what I did:

```
<target name="print_process_list">
    <echo message="print_process_list start"/>
    <echo message="${compile_project_lists} "/>
    <echo message="print_process_list end"/>
</target>
<target name="buildall" depends="print_process_list">
    <ac:for list="${compile_project_lists}" param="iprocess">
            <sequential>
            <exec executable="./ant_xml_pars.sh" outputproperty="ant_parstout.@{iprocess}" failonerror="false" >
                                    <arg value="@{iprocess}"/>
                            </exec>
                            <echo message="${ant_parstout.@{iprocess}} " />
        </sequential>
    </ac:for>
```